# Подгрузка контента AJAX-PHP

Tags: ajax, php, sql

Есть сайт - новостной портал.

Новости могут отображаться двумя способами (пользователь выбирает в настройках): обычный постраничный вывод и подгрузка при прокрутке до конца страницы.

Если с первым проблем нет, то со вторым возникли некоторые сложности. В частности, с сортировкой новостей.

Если мы выводим новости просто по порядку их ID, то проблем нет. Передаём через ajax в php скрипт ID последней и выводим следующую порцию новостей, у которых ID меньше, чем передан.

Если же у каждой новости есть свой рейтинг и вывод должен осуществляться **по количеству рейтинга**, то возникают сложности с синхронизацией или... не знаю, как это назвать. Каждый пользователь может изменить рейтинг новости, кликнув по новости, идёт запись в БД и соответственно рейтинг новости увеличивается или уменьшается.

Пример возникающей проблемы. Есть новости с определённым рейтингом:

> Новость 1 - рейтинг 10
>
> Новость 2 - рейтинг 9
>
> Новость 3 - рейтинг 8
>
> **Новость 4 - рейтинг 2**
>
> Новость 5 - рейтинг 1
>
> Новость 6 - рейтинг 0
>
> Новость 7 - рейтинг 0
>
> Новость 8 - рейтинг 1

Допустим, при открытии страницы, пользователь видит 4 новости, то есть:

> Новость 1 - рейтинг 10
>
> Новость 2 - рейтинг 9
>
> Новость 3 - рейтинг 8
>
> **Новость 4 - рейтинг 2**

Соответственно переменная offset (смещение), которую будем передавать в ajax - равна 4.

Если пользователь просто прокрутит страницу до конца, **не меняя рейтинг новостей и другие пользователи в этот момент не меняют рейтинг новостей**, то проблемы не возникнет, произойдёт подгрузка новостей со смещения 4 и потом в переменную offset запишется новое значение для следующей подгрузки, если ещё остались новости.

**НО, если же, пока пользователь видит только 4 новости, другие пользователи или он сам изменят рейтинг новости (например, у новости 4 рейтинг станет 0), то соответственно она будет подгружена второй раз, то есть будут подгружены новости *5,4,6,7*, а не *5,6,7,8*.**

Код запроса:

```
SELECT p.*
FROM posts p
ORDER BY p.rating DESC
LIMIT $limit OFFSET $ofset
```

Как быть? Можно, конечно, после подгрузки, пробежаться по всем записям в DOM и удалить повторяющиеся, но этот вариант заведомо провальный, а всё остальное пока мне не даёт нужного результата.

Comment: Напрашивающийся ответ - ведите массив из идентификаторов уже загруженных новостей. И по нему потом фильтруйте следующие новости в sql запросе. Либо при каждом ajax запросе формируйте этот массив и отправляйте, либо на стороне сервера ведите его. Где хранить в таком случае - как вам удобнее. Каждая полноценная загрузка страницы будет сбрасывать этот массив.

Comment: Этот вариант пришёл в голову одним из первых, но я его отбросил почти сразу не попробовав, ссылаясь на очень сильную потерю производительности. 

Если допустим, пользователь уже просмотрел много новостей и сейчас на странице 500 новостей, то каждый SQL запрос будет содержать что-то вроде:
WHERE p.id NOT IN (1,2,3,4,5...,500)

И кроме того, ещё потеря времени на получение списка ID новостей, либо надо с помощью each пробегать все dom-элементы новостей, вытаскивая ID и отправлять на сервер, либо на сервере делать ещё один запрос и получать записи.

Comment: Мне кажется у Вас нет логики поведения отображения - если изменился порядок, то в принципе не правильно тягать новый порядок. Например, какое поведение должно быть, если человек сначала прочитал первую новость, а потом она стала 10000?

Comment: Да, неправильно. То есть получается формировать на клиенте список уже отображенных ID новостей и потом отправлять на сервер для проверки - идеальный вариант? 

Отвечая на ваш вопрос, если новость была первой, а потом стала 10000, то при подгрузке она, не должна выводиться, т.к. она уже есть на странице. Только после обновления страницы, она станет 10000-й.

Пока что сделал так: при создании страницы собираю id всех новостей в массив, при прокрутке до конца отправляю всё это дело на сервер и сравниваю NOT IN..., после добавления новостей добавляю в массив новые айдишники новостей.

Comment: Мне кажется, лучше отсылать при первом запросе клиенту список всей айдюков в нужном порядке, а клиент только дёргает запрос контента по айдюку

Comment: Не совсем понял вас. Если у меня 20000 новостей в БД, вы предлагаете отправить клиенту 20000 id номеров, при условии, что пользователь может даже не докрутит страницу и до тысячной новости?

Comment: отправляйте 1000 новостей. потом один фиг браузер начнёт нереально тормозить, и надо будет перегружать. В любом случае Вам надо порядок зафиксировать тем или иным способом первый раз. Можно на стороне сервера его зафиксировать. иначе всегда будет "что-то не то".

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Общая идея решения, чтобы разделить посты и рейтинги по разным таблицам, то есть таблица рейтинга будет иметь вид:

```
| id | post_id | datetime         | value |
| 1  | 1       | 2015-03-20 10:00 | 5     |
| 2  | 1       | 2015-03-20 12:00 | -1    |
| 3  | 1       | 2015-03-20 15:00 | 3     |
| 4  | 1       | 2015-03-20 16:00 | -2    |
```

Тогда можно расчитать рейтинг на конкретный период времени, указав время:

```
SELECT sum(value) FROM rating WHERE datetime < '2015-03-20 15:00' GROUP BY post_id
```

Теперь объединяем все вместе:

```
SELECT
    p.*, (SELECT
        sum(value)
    FROM rating
    WHERE datetime < {$date}
    AND post_id = p.id) AS rating
ORDER BY rating DESC
LIMIT 5 OFFSET {$offset}
```

Параметры `{$date}` и `{$offset}` присылает пользователь date - это дата, для которой происходит расчет рейтинга.